# Make AutoMapper ignore all my EF-relevant properties (of generic type)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, automapper, entitycollection

Based on a number of posts here on SO, I am trying to create an extension method for AutoMapper so that for all my EF 4.0 business objects, all the EF-relevant properties of types `EntityReference<T>` and `EntityCollection<T>` are excluded from a mapping.

I have come up with this code:

```
public static class IgnoreEfPropertiesExtensions {
    public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> IgnoreEfProperties<TSource, TDestination>(
        this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression) {
        var sourceType = typeof (TSource);

        foreach (var property in sourceType.GetProperties()) {
            // exclude all "EntityReference" and "EntityReference<T>" properties
            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(EntityReference) || 
                property.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(EntityReference)))
            {
                expression.ForMember(property.Name, opt => opt.Ignore());
            }

            // exclude all "EntityCollection<T>" properties
            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(EntityCollection<>))
            {
                expression.ForMember(property.Name, opt => opt.Ignore());
            }
        }

        return expression;
    }
}
```

but somehow, while it works just fine the `EntityReference<T>` properties, for the collection, this doesn't do what it should do - AutoMapper still tries to map the `EntityCollection<MySubEntity>` and crashes on attempting this....

How can I properly catch all the `EntityCollection<T>` properties? I don't really care about what the subtype `<T>` is - I don't want to specify that, **all** properties of type `EntityCollection<T>` (regardless of what the collection contains) need to be excluded from the mapping.

Any ideas?